# PowerBuilder 12.5 error while starting "the application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect."

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net

I just install `PowerBuilder 12.5`, I did not get any error while installation. after finish the installation I am trying to open the `PowerBuilder` from the `Start Menu`. the movement I click on it. it will show below message.

[image]

I have installed `PowerBuilder 12.5` twice, but facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a message from the PB12.NET version.  It runs inside the Visual Studio isolated shell, so there must be some incompatibility with a separate install of Visual Studio already on your computer.

Were you intending to run the .NET version?  Does the PB12 Classic version launch correctly?

-Paul Horan-
IBM